# SVG images gains weird offset while importing into Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, svg, swiftui

I need to understand why Xcode does that to me. I mean when importing SVG file, Xcode modifies it and adds offset for text.[image]

Image on the left side is shown by Xcode, the right one of course is the actual image.

To be sure, I've tried to add image as asset to assets folder and also tried to add as standard file, same result.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. But BTW that image looks like it is too big (goes outside of bounds) vs offset but without a

Comment: These are the [Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/visual/layout/) for the sizes that the Apple Watch screens support

Comment: Convert text objects to outlines.