# SVG file looks different when adding to Xcode and not showing edits

Tags: xcode, image, svg, vector, assets

I'm creating graphics in Affinity Designer and exporting them as a SVG file, however, when I add them to Xcode as an asset the images do not appear exactly how they do in Affinity Designer, or if you preview them elsewhere.

It's inconsistent, odd behaviour and sometimes edits DO show, making it impossible to find the cause -- it's as if the file is not updating with the edits and shows a "historic" version instead.

In the example below, I'll move the left-hand line to the right and flip it horizontally. However, in Xcode it doesn't reflect this.

[File in Affinity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hZW8.png)

[Edits not shown in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO7gi.png)

The closest thing I can find anywhere to this problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65807244/svg-images-gains-weird-offset-while-importing-into-xcode), with a suggestion to 'convert text objects to lines' - but that's not applicable here (I don't think).

Comment: You'd need to include the markup i.e. the file contents in the question.

Comment: That's quite a lot of text, not sure how is best to share that?

Comment: Cut it down to a [mcve] with the emphasis on minimal.

Comment: I think you may have led me towards the issue. Trying to be succinct: at some point I have Rasterized the layers (turning it to a 'Pixel' layer) so I can clip them with selection tools. The markup of the SVG export is then huge, containing lots of text that doesn't look like XML but rather just unstructured numbers and letters. If I roughly recreate the file with just Curve layers and export, it then has very little text which is all clear and relatable to XML. My guess is it can't translate Pixel layers to XML properly?